# Пропадают куки после закрытия браузера

Tags: php, apache, cookie

Собственно тема и есть вопросом.
Вот так задаю куки на год:

```
    setcookie( 'login', encrypt($login), time() + (86400 * 365), '/' );
    setcookie( 'phoneNumber', encrypt($phoneNumber), time() + (86400 * 365), '/' );
    setcookie( 'name', encrypt($name), time() + (86400 * 365), '/' );
    setcookie( 'department', encrypt($department), time() + (86400 * 365), '/' );
```

В консоле разработчика Chrome они отображаються, expired тоже верно, путь - корень, то есть для всего сайта.

При закрытии браузера и открытии заново, читаю куки так

```
if( !isset($_COOKIE['login']) || !isset($_COOKIE['name']) || !isset($_COOKIE['phoneNumber']) ) {
header('Location: login.php');
die;
}
```

Но в массиве $_COOKIE лежит только сессионная пара, а вышеуказанных значений нет :(

Настройки браузера правильные, браузер корректно хранит куки других сайтов.
Моё творение крутится на CentOS, PHP-5.4.16, настройки по дефолту.

Буду благодарен за любую подсказку.

Comment: Что-то я не понял, вы проверяете `$_COOKIE['drivers']`, но `setcookie` для него нету

Comment: Вы правы, промазал, но ситуацию не спасло, куки пропадают после рестарта браузера

Comment: Как вы проверяете, что массив $_COOKIE пуст?

Comment: с помощью isset($_COOKIE['login'])

Comment: Это вы проверяете отдельную куку. Если отдельной куки нет, это совершенно не значит, что весь массив $_COOKIE пуст.

Comment: он не пуст, вы правы, там лежит сессионная пара значений и всё

Comment: а браузер не настроен на удаление кук после закрытия?

Comment: Настройки браузера правильные, браузер корректно хранит куки других сайтов.

Comment: Если переменная пуста, то кука не создается. Попробуйте заменить || на && в if. Если не поможет, попробуйте выводить $_COOKIE на экран (или запишите в файл), посмотрите что там есть. Проверил ваш код у себя - у меня куки сохраняются. Может проверяете в режиме инкогнито?

Comment: В Opera всё работает как ожидается, закрываешь браузер, открываешь - куки на месте, проблема в Chrome, в частности "chrome://settings/content/cookies" пункт "Удалять локальные данные при закрытии браузера" который включен и не выключается, пишет что "Это параметр включен администратором". Настройки сбрасывал, реестр проверял, вирусов нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спустя 2 часа:

1. сброса настроек Chrome
2. экспериментирование с флагами
3. запуском под разными пользователями
4. проверка Chrome на других машинах
5. проверка других браузеров (кстате они отрабатывали корректно в частности куки).

было найдено и установлено, что параметр "CookieDefaultProtect" который находится в реестре

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google

установлен в "4", удаление ключа реестра и перезаход в систему помог.

Comment: Не гуглится ничего по данному параметру... Где откопали информацию?

Comment: Я нагуглил как убрать поисковую систему по-умолчанию, которую нельзя изменить, там было предложено проверить реестр и убрать соответствующее значение, я пошел туда и случайно увидел ключ реестра со словом Cookie, сначала его менял и перезаходил, потом просто удалил, перезашёл в систему и всё завелось.